# Is it possible to charge with USB-C PD, run 4k@60hz with HDMI, and run 3 USB 2.0 from a single USB-C hub?

Tags: usb, hdmi, ethernet, hub, 4k

I'm having 2 workstations, 3 laptops. Got bored of plugging in-out all the cables every time I switch laptops/workstations. My plan is to just buy 2 hubs for the 2 workstations, and I only have to plug one cable. I'm really hoping it's possible.

I know each port has it's own limitations. I just don't understand the exact numbers. Ideally I would like to (at the same time):

- run an external monitor 4k@60hz
- charge (I don't care about speed, just charge at least the amount of power that it's using)
- have ethernet through LAN@500Mbps (if this is the deciding factor, I'm happy with wifi)
- run an external laptop fan through USB 2.0
- run a Magic Keyboard through USB 2.0
- run a Magic Trackpad 2 through USB 2.0

I don't need anything else. If it's impossible, I can split into two, but I have only one USB C available, the other hub needs to be USB A (3.0).

So the question is: is this possible? I would be curious about the breakdown as well about the power, and data/time limitations of ports, usage etc.

Comment: Thunderbolt 3 can do it all at once

Answer (score 1):

A Thunderbolt 3 hub should work.  If you are using a MacBook with a USB C port, it supports Thunderbolt.  If you are using a Windows laptop, let me know what computer model is and I'll let you know if your laptop has Thunderbolt 3 on it.

A Thunderbolt hub can have many outputs, so you will have to find the one that is tailored to your needs.  From reading your question, it seems like [this hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08K3XZB43) should fit your needs.  It has one DisplayPort output at 4k 60hz, three USB A ports, a gigabit Ethernet port, and it can charge the computer all through one USB C cable.

Answer (score 1):

We have USB type C docking stations that have 4 USB ports.  2 are USB 2.0, and 2 are USB 3.0

It provide 100% power to the laptop

Gigabit networking

They also run 2 1080p displays at the same time.

I haven't look at the specs so I don't know if it support 4k, but I imaging there are docking stations that support 4k@60hz.